# How to pronounce "Where're" in English?

Tags: pronunciation

Ok, in dictionary, **where** `/wer/` [Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where)

& **'re**  `/ɚ/` [Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/re?q=%27re)

So, **where're** will be pronounced as  `/werɚ/`, right?

Comment: I don't even bother using "where're", I usually would use "where's" or leave it uncontracted.

Answer (score 4):

I'm an American English speaker.

At the end of *where*, my mouth is already in the right shape to say the /r/ sound for *'re*.  So I just **keep my mouth in the same position** and keep making the same /r/ sound.

There may also be a brief dip in intensity marking the boundary between the two /r/ sounds.  In other words, **my voice may very briefly get quieter in the middle**, separating the sound into *where* and *'re*.  This is called rearticulation.

Comment: As another American English speaker, I agree.  This is probably going to be very difficult for a non-native speaker to hear, though.  Even we Americans understand it more by context than by literal pronunciation, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a native speaker with an amalgamation of American, Canadian, and slightly British accents (due to my upbringing). I say the word `where` first, with my tongue slightly pulled back at the end of the word then I slightly emphasise the `'re` — not particularly louder but to show it as separate from the word `where` and do so by pulling my tongue back a little more.

I do that or just emphasise and slightly lengthen the end of the word `where` to show I'm asking about the location of something.

Here are some links from Forvo (a great online pronunciation dictionary) to the words "where" and "where're". I'd compare the male American pronunciations of the word `where` to the sole pronunciation of the word `where're` to differentiate the entries best.

1. **where**: http://forvo.com/word/where/#en
2. **where're**: http://forvo.com/word/where%27re/#en